# overwriting the column rows basis the condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Existing Dataframe :

```
Id           condition1        condition2       score
A               attempt           pass            0
A               attempt           fail            0
B               attempt           pass            0
B               attempt           level_1         0
B               attempt           fail            0
C               attempt           fail            0
D               attempt           fail            0
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
Id           condition1        condition2       score
A               attempt           pass            1
A               attempt           fail            1
B               attempt           pass            1
B               attempt           level_1         1
B               attempt           fail            1
C               attempt           fail            0
D               attempt           fail            0
```

I am looking to tag score in **every row** of unique Id as 1 if in any row below condition is satisfied : condition1 == 'attempt' & condition2 =='pass'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
m1 = df['condition1'].eq('attempt')
m2 = df['condition2'].eq('pass') | df['condition2'].eq('level_1')

df['score'] = (m1 & m2)
df['score'] = df.groupby('Id')['score'].transform(lambda x: x.any().astype(int))

  Id condition1 condition2  score
0  A    attempt       pass      1
1  A    attempt       fail      1
2  B    attempt       pass      1
3  B    attempt    level_1      1
4  B    attempt       fail      1
5  C    attempt       fail      0
6  D    attempt       fail      0
```

Comment: thanks.! what if we need to check attempt and level_1, if any Id have either pass or level_1 we need to tag it as 1, what would be the change in code.?

Comment: You mean condition2 equal to level_1 also considered as pass?

Comment: yes instead of pass , if we want to check appearance of pass or level_1, if any one of the two appears we need to tag all the row of that Id as 1

Comment: Ok check my updates please.